# How to dynamically update popover content AngularJS Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I use custom AngularJs directive for create bootstrap popover but when make popover popover content can't change and it's fix .

```
 app.directive('nextLevel', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<a ui-sref="register" tabindex="0" linkdisabled="{{type}}"
 class="btn btn-block btn-success ng-class: {disabled: !(type)}" role="button" >next</a>',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs){
                $(el).popover({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    html: true,
                    toggle:'popover',   
                    title: 'notice !!',
                    content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                    placement: 'top'
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

my html is :

```
<next-level id='pop' popover-html='{{typeMessage}}'></next-level>
```

***typeMessage*** should be change depending on user behavior but it's only show initial message and not change content when popover open .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should isolate the scope with '@' binding inorder to reflect the change

```
app.directive('nextLevel', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope:{ popoverHtml:'@'}, // Isolated the scope 
            template: '<a ui-sref="register" tabindex="0" linkdisabled="{{type}}"
 class="btn btn-block btn-success ng-class: {disabled: !(type)}" role="button" >next</a>',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs){
                $(el).popover({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    html: true,
                    toggle:'popover',   
                    title: 'notice !!',
                    content: scope.popoverHtml,  // Access the popoverHtml html
                    placement: 'top'
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Update:

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wfC4DrTIp8fRIs6hEEDa?p=preview)

When you click on radio button, pop over will disappear and pop over content will be updated.

Comment: Yes. You should use type-message='{{typeMessage}}' and change scope:{ typeMessage: '@'}, . Is it working right now?

Comment: Name your directive as app.directive('nextLevel',

Comment: Take a look at this https://plnkr.co/edit/5pV1k4qjGdfJCOxZR1AE?p=preview

Comment: ok thanks it's work fine . but why linkdisabled="{{type}}" not work i think for scope

Comment: You want popover only on click event right... So, try this https://plnkr.co/edit/wfC4DrTIp8fRIs6hEEDa?p=preview . It will hide pop over when you click on radio button.

Comment: Do you want to pass "type" from main controller or is it a variable in directive?

Comment: "type" is in the main controller . i try this but not work scope: {popoverHtml: '@', type: '@'},

Comment: Did you pass it from html? Is type a primitive variable or a object. You can pass only variables like this type: '@'. If you want to pass object then type: '='

Comment: in my controller $scope.type= true; when i comment this line scope: {popoverHtml: '@'}, this issue is for scope: {popoverHtml: '@'},

Comment: ng-class="disabled?  where do you this disabled variable from?

Comment: disabled is a style from bootstrap and i want when type is false a tag set inactive otherwise active

Comment: See this...https://plnkr.co/edit/z5yXiAVaMEyHBsJsXFLu?p=preview. You cannot send `type` as '@'. If you do changes will not be reflected in `ng-class`. In order to reflect changes in `ng-class` you have to pass it as an object.

Comment: Feel free to accept this as an answer if you feel actual question is answered.

Comment: What is bs.popover ?